# Changing figsize results in empty output image

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to save a plot with a transparent background using `savefig`. The code looks like this:

```
plt.savefig("filename.png", transparent=True)
plt.show()
```

It works well and saves the images as expected (some graphs on a transparent background). However, if I change the size of the plot, the output image becomes an empty image, that is, a completely transparent image with no graphs. This is how I changed the size:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(6.4, 4.8), dpi=100)
plt.savefig("filename.png", transparent=True)
plt.show()
```

I want a 640x480 image. Even if I don't change the dpi the output images are completely blank. How can i avoid this?

Comment: What happens moving `plt.figure(figsize=(6.4, 4.8), dpi=100)` at the beginning of the plotting code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4306340/11345381

Comment: `plt.figure()` creates a figure. Directly after you create it you save it, so it has no content. See the duplicate on how to set the figure size.

Comment: @sentence that solved my problem, thank you. Also the people who marking this as duplicate, the links you provide don't answer my question.

Comment: @AsierR. : This is the relevant duplicate: [figsize-in-matplotlib-is-not-changing-the-figure-size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52274643/figsize-in-matplotlib-is-not-changing-the-figure-size)